# Weird behaviour in Array.fill

Tags: javascript, arrays

When i use Array.fill to fill a multidimensional array, i get a weird behaviour when pushing to one of the arrays:

```
var arr = Array(2).fill([]);
arr[0].push(5);
console.log(arr); 
//=> prints [[5], [5]]
```

Comment: both given answers are great examples of why you should learn about objects and how they work. mozilla developer network would be a good start for learning about this. tbh you could even do this: `var a = {}; (function(x){a.foo="bar"})(a); console.log(a.foo)`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`fill` is essentially doing this:

```
var content = [];
for (var i = 0; i < 2; i += 1) {
  arr[i] = content;
}
```

So, your array will have a reference to the array you've passed to `fill` in each property.

Answer (score 2):

It sounds weird, but what your code actually does is create an array (`[]`) and put a reference for that array in each of the items of the `Array(2)`. So whenever you change that reference - every array that is referenced to that Array is changed.

It's exactly the same as:

```js
var a = [];
var arr = Array(2).fill(a);
a.push(5);
console.log(arr[0][0], arr[1][0]);
a[0] = 2;
console.log(arr[0][0], arr[1][0]);
```

You can see that the values inside the `arr` are affected by the change to the `a` array.